# How to edit max query size with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a very long query (3MB) to execute and I use PDO to do this but I have a problem: the query is too long.

I already changed the MySQL variable max_allowed_packet to 100MB but it didn't resolve the problem, so i guess it is because of PDO.

I saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118424/php-mysql-pdo-maximum-query-size) but MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE doesn't seem to exist:
**Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE'**

How can i resolve it ?

Comment: Is this one big query or a combination of multiple queries ?

Comment: did you also Google that error? quite a few hits on the subject

Comment: [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php): "This constant is not supported when compiled against mysqlnd." aka any recent version of PHP.

Comment: Zeratops it is only 1 big query.

Fred-ii- i did, I found nothing

Comment: if you're running this from local and made any changes to system files, did you restart everything?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i already restarted the computer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined class constant 'MYSQL\_ATTR\_INIT\_COMMAND' with pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424343/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-with-pdo)